# Can't endBackgroundTask

Tags: objective-c, background

Im trying to replicate what in this blog is explained, http://developer.blueearth.net/2011/12/02/quick-tip-clearing-up-ios-multitasking/, 
It explains a way of having a NSTimer running in the background endlesly.

The problem is that after 10 mins I get this.

```
Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 2b55e8, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug
```

And then 4 minutes after the app stops executing

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

2b55e8 doesn't sound like a good identifier, but I might be wrong. In my app on iOS 6 they start from 1 and are printed out as integers by that error message, not as hex values.