# Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 4, or it may have already been ended

Tags: ios, objective-c

Implemented the timer in the background as follows and using the XCode 4.5.2

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
        backgroundSupported = YES;
    }

    if (backgroundSupported) 
    {
        bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];

      /*timer code goes here*/
    }
```

and my app is running in background and I have the above code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method in AppDelegate and getting the following message in gdb

**Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 4, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.**

I know this question is similar to [Can't endBackgroundTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722465/cant-endbackgroundtask) but no answer or suggestions there. any ideas ?

Comment: What is the type of `bgtask`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are declaring `bgTask` like so: `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;`

I think you may have `bgTask` declared as an int or NSNumber.

Comment: Xcode gives a compiler warning when trying to set bgTask to nil.

Comment: Updated my answer to an appropriate default value.