# Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 23?

Tags: ios, ios7, keyboard, uitextfield

I know this might be a duplicate question, I getting this in log.

> Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 23, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629228/cant-endbackgroundtask-no-background-task-exists-with-identifier-4-or-it-may