# UIBackgroundTask throws error `no background task exists`

Tags: ios, swift, uibackgroundtask

An `AVAudioPlayer` is stopped in a background tasks when the app transitions to background:

```
func stop() {

    var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask() {

        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {

        self.audioPlayer?.pause()

        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid // Symbolic breakpoint stops here
    }
}
```

The function above gets called by the view controller that contains the `AVAudioPlayer` when a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` notification is posted.

Still I get an error at line `backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid`:

```
// Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1f, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.`
```

When I remove the line I get no errors. I looked through similar questions on SO but they did not help.

What is causing this error?

Comment: your background task is already ended in your first block of code then you are ending it again may be this is the cause for the error.

Comment: @iOSDev I put a breakpoint on the code inside the termination handler, from that I can tell that it doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: I found a solution. I hope it helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763049/1890317