# App is getting crashed on app launch in iOS 13 beta version

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios13

Here is the crash report and the crash is only happening on iOS 13 beta version :-

```
 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
 0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ae056484 pthread_get_qos_class_np + 8
 1  Foundation                     0x1ae664340 -[NSThread qualityOfService] + 80
 2  Foundation                     0x1ae626ebc -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 280
 3  Foundation                     0x1ae628df8 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 116
 4  libAXSpeechManager.dylib       0x1d0176884 -[AXSpeechManager isSpeaking] + 112
 5  libAXSpeechManager.dylib       0x1d0171b60 -[AXSpeechManager _didBeginInterruption] + 52
 6  libAXSpeechManager.dylib       0x1d0171f1c -[AXSpeechManager _handleAudioInterruption:] + 504
 7  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae2929ac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
 8  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae2929f4 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 64
 9  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae291d54 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 368
 10 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae291a20 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 104
 11 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae20dd38 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1416
 12 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae291370 _CFXNotificationPost + 1244
 13 Foundation                     0x1ae5edcf8 -[NSNotificationCenter  postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
 14 AVFAudio                       0x1bac4603c -[AVAudioSession privateInterruptionWithInfo:] + 988
 15 AVFAudio                       0x1bac4880c (anonymous namespace)::HandlePropertyListenerCallback(unsigned int, objc_selector*, NSObject*) + 68
 16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ae004658 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
 17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ae0051cc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
 18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1adfe83e0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 996
 19 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae2b4c74 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
 20 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae2afc68 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
 21 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae2af16c CFRunLoopRunSpecific +  464
 22 GraphicsServices               0x1b80d9328 GSEventRunModal + 104
 23 UIKitCore                      0x1b2317f6c UIApplicationMain + 1936
 24 Quickride                      0x10086803c main + 37 (AppDelegate.swift:37)
 25 libdyld.dylib                  0x1ae13a424 start + 4
```

I have checked on various platforms for this issue. But have not found any solution related to it.Please provide any solution related to it.

It is crashing on app launch itself and this is the report it shows on fabric

Comment: Did you make sure to upgrade to the latest Fabric and make any updates to the code as necessary?

Comment: This isn't related to Fabric. We are seeing it in our app occasionally as well, and we don't use Fabric. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to repro this crash ourselves.

Comment: Same for us. This is now our top crash. It seems to occur when app is in background, regardless the amount of time spent in background. 

And most important, this occurs in final iOS 13.1 maybe can you update the title of this topic

Comment: we have the same question on iOS 13.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue on iOS 13 and it's my most serious crash on Crashlytics.
It occurs only in iOS 13 and above. Unfortunately also in the latest 13.1.2.

Starting by the iOS 13 release I've detected a strange warning when I put my app in background the debug console print *Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier x, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.*

Maybe the issues are related.

Comment: Same issue on me from iOS 13... ```Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 6 (0x6), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.``` Today I just fix 4 issues on specific iOS 13. What happened on iOS 13:(