# WatchOS 6 TTS bug ? AXSpeechManager isSpeaking crash

Tags: ios13, watchos-6

Here is the bug report. I think it's a bug of watchOS 6 something related to apple Text to Speech service.

When i not use tts, it's go away.

```
Incident Identifier: 3C86B3F2-0565-464C-921C-A0ECB63237EB
CrashReporter Key:   9de6d125d2514512fa87c39b4cc898e09cf8d8cc
Hardware Model:      Watch4,4
Process:             LeanWatchApp Extension [367]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D8EC0163-C8EA-4375-B556-3C751744EEE3/LeanWatchApp.app/PlugIns/LeanWatchApp Extension.appex/LeanWatchApp Extension
Identifier:          hltek.Lean.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
Version:             4 (1.15)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           hltek.Lean.watchkitapp.watchkitextension [473]


Date/Time:           2019-10-08 08:45:38.1157 +0800
Launch Time:         2019-10-08 08:42:38.0000 +0800
OS Version:          Watch OS 6.0.1 (17R605)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000195eb0c0
VM Region Info: 0x195eb0c0 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 553153  Bytes before following region: 104714048
      REGION TYPE              START - END     [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      Stack                  194dc000-19564000 [  544K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 5
--->  GAP OF 0x6464000 BYTES
      unused shlib __TEXT    1f9c8000-1f9ee000 [  152K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ... this process

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [367]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1fd6a670 pthread_get_qos_class_np + 8
1   Foundation                      0x20adf988 -[NSThread qualityOfService] + 80
2   Foundation                      0x20aa24e8 -[NSObject+ 271592 (NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 272
3   Foundation                      0x20aa43f4 -[NSObject+ 279540 (NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 116
4   libAXSpeechManager.dylib        0x437a88f0 -[AXSpeechManager isSpeaking] + 112
5   libAXSpeechManager.dylib        0x437a3c38 -[AXSpeechManager _didBeginInterruption] + 52
6   libAXSpeechManager.dylib        0x437a3fec -[AXSpeechManager _handleAudioInterruption:] + 500
7   CoreFoundation                  0x200bb1d0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
8   CoreFoundation                  0x200bb218 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x200ba580 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 368
10  CoreFoundation                  0x200ba24c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 104
11  CoreFoundation                  0x20037fec -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1392
12  CoreFoundation                  0x200b9bc8 _CFXNotificationPost + 1188
13  Foundation                      0x20a694c0 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
14  AVFAudio                        0x2ac2048c -[AVAudioSession privateInterruptionWithInfo:] + 992
15  AVFAudio                        0x2ac22c30 (anonymous namespace)::HandlePropertyListenerCallback+ 597040 (unsigned int, objc_selector*, NSObject*) + 72
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1fb333a0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x1fb34730 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x1fb405a8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 992
19  CoreFoundation                  0x200dbe6c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
20  CoreFoundation                  0x200d6a10 __CFRunLoopRun + 740
21  CoreFoundation                  0x200d6420 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
22  GraphicsServices                0x236462ec GSEventRunModal + 100
23  UIKitCore                       0x3ca1f784 UIApplicationMain + 1760
24  libxpc.dylib                    0x1fdc4aa4 _xpc_objc_main.cold.3 + 208
25  libxpc.dylib                    0x1fdb0a90 _xpc_objc_main + 212
26  libxpc.dylib                    0x1fdb33e4 xpc_main + 152
27  Foundation                      0x20aa663c +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
28  PlugInKit                       0x298462f8 0x2982d000 + 103160
29  WatchKit                        0x325c4f94 WKExtensionMain + 60
30  WatchKit                        0x325c4fb8 main + 12
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x1fb70a38 start + 4
```

It's very similar to this:
[App is getting crashed on app launch in iOS 13 beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847960/app-is-getting-crashed-on-app-launch-in-ios-13-beta-version)

When make wrist down , the watch screen off ,It always crash. but my app is Workout app, it can work in background before watchOS 6.

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the stack trace for the other threads