# application:openUrl:options not called when opening app from share sheet of another app

Tags: swift, ios13, ios-sharesheet

I would like to open zip files with my app and configured the following:

Document Types
[image]

This leads to the desired appearing of my app in other app's share sheet. But when I tap my app in that share sheet, my app is opened, but the following method in my AppDelegate is never called:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

It's a iOS 13 application - what am I missing here?

Comment: Haven't tested but afaik, if the app is not launched then it will be available in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`. If app is in background then `application(_:open:options:)` should be called.

Comment: the app is running, then I'm switching to another app, open share sheet and select my app, so it should be running in background

Comment: What about `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`?

Comment: just returns `true`, but isn't called either

Comment: so none of the 3 methods are called: `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` / `application(_:open:options:)` / `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`?

Comment: exactly, yes. In the logs I see `Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.`

Comment: iOS 13 bug? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58083223/2857130

Comment: the question is if this is related (can't imagine as then no app could handle files...) or if I'm still missing something (pretty sure)

Comment: @swalkner I might be wrong here but I dont know if Apple allows passing zip files between apps. Have you tried it with a simple image. See if that works first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625433/341994

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your app is using scenes, then instead of `application(_:open:options:)` from `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, iOS will call `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` from `UISceneDelegate`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene

Also probably it's better to change `com.pkware.Zip-archive` to `com.pkware.zip-archive` as it's defined as lowercase in the list of [System-Declared UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)