# Swift application having weird behavior when closing it

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, face-id

I am developing an application that uses the Face/Touch ID at the opening.
I achieved this by adding this func to my MainViewController():

```
let context = LAContext()

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: nil) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Verifying") { (success, err) in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loginSuccessfull()
                    self.button.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            } else {
                if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets called both in the ViewDidLoad and by a button, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAr-rVbB35Q&feature=youtu.be).

As you can see tho, when I try to close my App it has a very weird behavior, and I am sure that it is caused by the FaceID.

Any suggestion to fix this?

Crash log:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-4 "Caller moved to background." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Caller moved to background.}
```

Comment: Can you describe what the weird part is -- I don't see it.

Comment: @LouFranco at the end, when I close the app, the phone crashes and goes to the home screen

Comment: Do you get a crash log you can share?

Comment: @koen 
`2019-12-24 22:27:06.660868+0100 DemoApp[3266:786877] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 13 (0xd), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-4 "Caller moved to background." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Caller moved to background.}
`

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882495/cant-endbackgroundtask-no-background-task-exists-with-identifier-or-it-may-ha

Comment: @koen the actual error is the following (I just debugged it a little more):
`Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-4 "Caller moved to background." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Caller moved to background.}`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue!, in my case the replay closure is called 2 times, one is in normal flow. the second time after force quit. I wonder why is that??

Comment: Do you have any code in AppDelegate `applicationDidResignActive` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: @Alexander in my SceneDelegate the `sceneDidResignActive` is empty and my `sceneDidEnterBackground` only has the `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()` line (already there as the app is using CoreData)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution for the issue, by delaying the evaluation.

I noticed that when I have any kind of delay in UI before evaluation (for example: animation that move the logo up before showing the face ID alert) the crash stops altogether.

So I did another test with delay like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let context = LAContext()
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Biometric test") { success, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        doSome()
                    } else {
                        if let error = error { print(error) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that implementation I had zero crashes.

*Note: I also tried different delay times, from 0.1 to 2.0 seconds, all worked for me.

Comment: Is there a minimum delay for this solution?

Comment: Your answer works, but really seems a "get around" and not a proper solution. Marked as solution anyway

Comment: I suspect when there is a bug, when calling evaluation before the controller is done rendering (after viewDidAppear)