# Xcode 11, Swift : Warning Can't end BackgroundTask on open URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just an application with 1 button and this the ViewController attached :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.fr")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```

When i click on the button, Safari open Google, i can come back to my app, but i have a warning message in the Xcode console :

```
2020-02-06 11:07:24.851814+0100 TabApp[6275:418659] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

Anyone know how to avoid this warning ?

Best regards

Comment: Which iOS and Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier, or it may have already been ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882495/cant-endbackgroundtask-no-background-task-exists-with-identifier-or-it-may-ha)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - this are typically logs from the OS.

Select your Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable`

[image]