# Running tasks at the background of my Application on Swift

Tags: swift, background-process

**couldn't find the right answer for my purposes, so I hope I didn't do anything wrong.**

well, I've got a timer app and I would like it to keep working once the user goes to the background, now I've read what apple said about running tasks at the background, but didn't get them right cause on one hand they say that running tasks at the background is aint that good, and the other case they say to release tasks and make sure that nothing runs at the background. if someone could help me with - **How to run a task at the background scene it could be awesome!**.

Comment: Awesome dude! couldn't find that thread for some reason :) thanks for the help, tbh I also thought about that(the solution that's inside the thread u posted)

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Comment: The answer is that you don’t keep the app running in the background. You just make sure that (a) you capture enough information so that if the app is restarted, you can recreate the timer, counting down to the appropriate time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642036/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862817/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048308/1271826...